# Within FreeBSD jail – setting global environment vars

Tags: freebsd, environment-variables, jail

I need to set a systemwide environment variable (i.e. NODE_ENV=production) in a FreeBSD jail.

I did try setting it in /etc/profile, but when I sourced it

```
root@www:/ # source /etc/profile
```

I got

```
export: Command not found.
```

It works on the host system.

I also tried setting it /.chsrc. But that only makes the variable availble to root but not any other users of the jail.

Comment: You appear to be running a shell that supports the `source` built-in but not `export`. E.g. `csh`. Try `setenv` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *"Set a systemwide environment variable in a FreeBSD jail."*

A: Set the variable both in `/etc/profile` and `/etc/csh.cshrc`.

---

Details

Quoting from [3.9. Shells](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/shells.html)

> *How to set an environment variable differs between shells. In tcsh(1) and csh(1), use setenv to set environment variables. In sh(1) and bash, use export to set the current environment variables.*

---

All examples below were executed in a jail

```
FreeBSD test_01.example.org 12.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE r341666 GENERIC  i386
```

---

**Users with default shell `sh` and `bash`**

`/etc/profile` is the right place to set global environment. For example

```
$ cat /etc/profile
NODE_ENV=production;    export NODE_ENV
```

Quoting from [profile(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=profile&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=SunOS+5.5.1&arch=default&format=html)

> *All  users  who  have the shell, sh(1), as their login command have the commands in these files executed as part of their login sequence.*

For example, the user `admin`

```
$ grep admin /etc/passwd
admin:*:1001:1001:User &:/home/admin:/bin/sh
```

executes `/etc/profile` *" as part of its login sequence"* and sets the environment

```
$ echo $NODE_ENV
production
```

This environment will be preserved both in `csh` and `tcsh`

```
$ csh
admin@test_01:~ % echo $NODE_ENV
production
```

It will be also preserved by `su`

```
$ su
root@test_01:/home/admin # echo $NODE_ENV
production
```

There is no `export` command in `csh` and `tcsh`. This explains the error

```
$ csh
admin@test_01:~ % source /etc/profile
NODE_ENV=production: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
```

---

**Users with default shell `csh` and `tcsh`**

`/etc/csh.cshrc` is the right place to set the global environment for `csh` and `tcsh`. For example

```
root@test_01:~ # cat /etc/csh.cshrc
setenv NODE_ENV production
```

Default shell of `root` is by default `csh`

```
root@test_01:~ # grep root /etc/passwd 
root:*:0:0:Charlie &:/root:/bin/csh
```

This sets the environment

```
root@test_01:~ # echo $NODE_ENV
production
```

Comment: Which shell uses the nginx process, e.g.?

Comment: It depends on how Nginx is started. FreeBSD uses the rc(8) system. See [12.4. Managing Services in FreeBSD](https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/configtuning-rcd.html). Review `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nginx` how to customize the environment. [Practical rc.d scripting in BSD](https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/rc-scripting/) might also help you.